# Facebook login manual flow with error

Tags: facebook, authentication, xamarin, web, oauth-2.0

After I dealt with this error a verified many fori and all mentioned that the solution for this error would be having in Facebook settings the “Valid OAuth Redirect URIs” set to “https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.htm”, what it is, so that is not the issue. Furthermore, all solutions found are too old and use obsolete components.

Said that using Xamarin Forms I’m trying to do the manual flow to login into Facebook as described in “https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow”.

The code is:

```
using Authentication.ViewModels;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace Authentication
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class FacebookProfilePage : ContentPage
{
    private string ClientId = "910688099117930";

    public FacebookProfilePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var apiRequest =
            "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
            + ClientId
            + "&display=popup&response_type=token&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html"
            + "&state=state123abc";

        var webView = new WebView
        {
            Source = apiRequest,
            HeightRequest = 1
        };

        webView.Navigated += WebViewOnNavigated;

        Content = webView;
    }

    private async void WebViewOnNavigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {

        var accessToken = ExtractAccessTokenFromUrl(e.Url);

        if (accessToken != "")
        {
            var vm = BindingContext as FacebookViewModel;

            await vm.SetFacebookUserProfileAsync(accessToken);

            Content = MainStackLayout;
        }
    }

    private string ExtractAccessTokenFromUrl(string url)
    {
        if (url.Contains("access_token") && url.Contains("&expires_in="))
        {
            var at = url.Replace("https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=", "");

            if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.WinPhone || Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Windows)
            {
                at = url.Replace("http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=", "");
            }

            var accessToken = at.Remove(at.IndexOf("&expires_in="));

            return accessToken;
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

}
```

Please, notice that this is a open code, found in “https://github.com/HoussemDellai/Facebook-Login-Xamarin-Forms”, which historically has proven itself to work fine.

The URL that I send to login is: “https://www.facebook.com/v3.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=910688099117930&response_type=token&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html”. I always get the error message: “Not Logged In: You are not logged in. Please login and try again.”.

Can anyone tell me what’s wrong here?

And before any comment, yes, I’ll delete this App Id as soon as the problem is solved and change it for a new one

Comment: Well at least your actually used redirect_uri should match your settings. // Where do you get that error message from, is that something coming from Facebook, or later on from your app itself?

Comment: It comes from Facebook... As soon as the webview is launched and send the URI, it returns the error... If I hand compose the URI and use in a browser, the same message returns....

Comment: When I try with an app of mine and open the login URL in a private tab, it asks me to login to Facebook at this point. Not sure how one could provoke it to show only the error you are getting (some app settings not right maybe); but I would recommend that you test in a normal desktop browser first and see that you get it working there; inside a webview there might be additional stuff going wrong.

Comment: I already did... In a private web browser, it gets the same error message...